# parameter is null while sending post request to webAPi from angularjs

Tags: javascript, c#, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to call one method but parameter is coming out as null

Server Side Code

```
[HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult PostRule(ActionRuleParameter actionRule)
        {
            // SOME CODE               
            return BadRequest();
        }

        public class ActionRuleParameter
        {
            public string action;
            public string rule;
        }
```

Client Side Code

```
addRule: function ($scope) {
            //var data = { "action": "post", "rule": { "ID": "1", "Name": "Ramesh", "PassFail": "Pass" } }

            var data1 = { "action": "post","rule":"rule" };


            $http({
                url: urlContent + '/api/Rules',
                method: "POST",
                data: { "actionRule": data1 }
            }).success(function (response) {
                $scope.rules = response;
            });;
        },
```

`action` and `rule` are coming out as null.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [FromBody] before your parameter

```
    public IHttpActionResult PostRule([FromBody]ActionRuleParameter actionRule)
    {
        // SOME CODE               
        return BadRequest();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this issue with Angular and the new ASP.NET stack. Adding [FromBody] fixed it for me so try:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public IHttpActionResult PostRule([FromBody]ActionRuleParameter actionRule)
 {
     // SOME CODE               
     return BadRequest();
 }
```